# How can i create a CSR (Certificate signing Request ) file in a Linux Ubuntu 13?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, csr

I'm trying to create a CSR file in an Ubuntu 13. How can I do it from the command line? I know how to do it from MAC OS in the KeyChain, but I actually don't have one.

This is what I tried in MAC OS:

Within the Keychain Access drop down menu, select Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority.

In the Certificate Information window, enter the following information:
In the User Email Address field, enter your email address.
In the Common Name field, create a name for your private key (e.g., John Doe Dev Key).
The CA Email Address field should be left empty.
In the "Request is" group, select the "Saved to disk" option.
Click Continue within Keychain Access to complete the CSR generating process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `openssl req` command, there are instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html

It's a little bit of a process but it will boil down to something along the lines of:

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

Comment: check this one: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following command to generate a CSR and private key:

**openssl req -new -keyout server.key -out server.csr**

You can follow the detail documentation regarding CSR below:

https://www.sslshopper.com/what-is-a-csr-certificate-signing-request.html